# why *.jsp url pattern in web.xml does not work

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

1. I wanna map all request to the TestHandler Servlet, so I use `/*` pattern.
2. Then I wanna exclude jsp mappings, so I add `*.jsp` pattern mapping to jsp in front of `/*`.
3. **Problem**: *.jsp doesn't catch the url `http://localhost/project/fun.jsp` at all. In stead, /* pattern catches it. Why? How can this happen ?

---

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TestHandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

But if I use a certain url-pattern like `fun.jsp` instead of `*.jsp`, it works. The `fun.jsp` pattern catch the url above. Who can tell me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patterns ending with `/*` (path rules) are matched before the `*.` starting (extension rules) mappings. The exact URI is an exact match, which is the 1st in the evaluation order.

Set `TestHandler` as default servlet, that should work.

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TestHandler</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: so, How can I change the order?

Comment: you can't, this is the servlet specification

Comment: You should try using `/` (and not `/*`) as url-pattern, which is the default servlet

Comment: Looks like `/` works very well. Thank you very much! But I don't understand the difference between `/` and `/*`! And where can find the documentation of this part (the url-pattern) ?

Comment: `/` is _THE_ default mapping, which is different from the `/*` ending mappings! This page explains it quite well: http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/ For the exact specification you have to check the Java Servlet specification I'm afraid...

Answer (score 1):

To write a servlet mapping there should a servlet class defined.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FULLY QUALIFIED NAME OF THE CLASS</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Please note :::: TestHandler is the servlet name and this servlet is mapped to url in the JSP (view) (url pattern /*)

Similarily for another servlet I am adding the servlet class

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FULLY QUALIFIED NAME OF THE CLASS</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

This all lines of code should be written in web.xml

Comment: Thank you! I know what you mean. I have the `<servlet-class>` part.
 But actually, `jsp` is a servlet defined in Tomcat/conf/web.xml.